# How to call UISwitch declared in Custom Cell in Table View ViewDidLoad method ?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, tableview, uiswitch

I have a `TableView` with a custom Cell having `UILabel` and `UISwitch`. UISwitch is declared in Custom Cell. I want to call this switch in `ViewDidLoad` of TableView. 
I want to use `NSUserDefaults` for saving states of UISwitch. To load the values I have to write the code in ViewDidLoad.

```
@interface LabelSwitchCustomCell : UITableViewCell {
    IBOutlet UILabel  *mainLabel;
    IBOutlet UISwitch *switchButton;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel  *mainLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISwitch *switchButton;

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save states for your UISwitch in NSUserDefaults from anywhere in your code. 
You can set/load switch state in this way:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
//Set switch states
    if (indexPath.row == 0) 
                cell.switchBtn.on = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"Switch1State"];
            else if(indexPath.row == 1)
                cell.switchBtn.on = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"Switch2State"];
            else if(indexPath.row == 2)
                cell.switchBtn.on = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"Switch3State"];
// Set switch states

// Set action for your switch
[cell.switchBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(switchingBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But the switch states remain True all time. Even on simulator if I turn off switch it again changes to True state

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexpath
{
    LabelSwitchCustomCell *switchCell = (LabelSwitchCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"YOUR_CELL_IDENTIFIER"];
    switchCell.switchButton.on = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"SwitchState"];
}
```

Then, in Interface Builder, connect the switch with this action declared and implemented in your custom cell class:

```
- (IBAction)switchFlipped:(id)sender
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:self.switchButton.on forKey:@"SwitchState"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But the switch states remain True all time. Even on simulator if I turn off switch it again changes to True state –